# Significance for raw and absoulte values in repeated measures

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

We are running repeated measures ANOVA with 2 independed and 1 depended variables.

The goal of our study to examine precision in participant's estimations about depended variable. This depended variable is calculated as difference between a normative critetia (some math formula) and participant's estimation, and varies from (-10) to (10). Let's name it ΔX.

When we do repeated measures ANOVA with raw values of ΔX we get significant main effect for the first independed variable but not for the second one. When we take absolute values (|ΔX|), we get significant main effect for the second independed variable, and not for the first one. There was no significant interaction in both cases.

Since we estimate precision in participant's estimation, it looks like more appropriate to take absoulte values of ΔX. But also we have a feeling that we miss something important about interpreting the results. Should we focus only on absolute values according to the question in our study (estimating precision of participants), or maybe we should do some data manipulation to the raw values?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that repeated measures ANOVA is considered to be obsolete by the marjority of statisticians, because it assumes a correlation structure that is two inflexible.  Look at the chart in section 7.3 of [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) for more information and for better alternatives.

In your special case where you compute the difference between a sampled value and a known constant, it is quite reasonable to analyze the original directional differences and to also analyze the undirectional absolute differences.  This will allow you to describe "how far off" the participants are as a function of participant characteristics.  But the distribution of absolute values will be more non-normal than the original signed differences, and parametric methods may not fit adequately.  I suggest using a random effects (one random effect per subject, with random effects assumed to be normal with a finite single variance) in a proportional odds ordinal logistic model. The semiparametric proportional odds ordinal model does not assume a shape for the distribution of absolute values, so allows it to be the skewed distribution that it is.

There are two R packages that will do this in the frequentist domain.  The `ordinal` package is one of them.  Bayesian modeling will provide more exact inference and there are many Bayesian modeling packages that will fit the longitudinal proportional odds model with random effects, e.g., `brms` and `rmsb` and `rstanarm`.